# Setting Margins -- expecting pixels, gettings dps?

Tags: android, android-emulator

This is one of those annoying cases where things are working but I don't know why.  Based on the Android API docs and this site, I expected to have to do pixel density conversions on my layout parameters (shown here in their original state):

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.width = 60;   // the following three should be pixels, right??
            lp.height = 80;              
            lp.setMargins(1, 5, 1, 5);
```

In other words, I expected the above to not work well across different screen densities since they're specified in pixels.  The "problem" is that it works fine on all of the simulators I've tried, from a lowly QVGA on up.  To try to understand why, I used Hierarchy Viewer to inspect my app and found that the width of the view (from getWidth()) was always 320 when my app had focus.  Go back to the home screen, say, and now HV reports the screen width as 480.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Weird. According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html they should indeed be pixels (search the page for 'or a fixed size in pixels'). Maybe there's some kind of forced resolution for Java apps, while the rest of the device threats the screen as the default resolution?

Comment: I think it's got to be something with the simulator, or rather the way my app is being built and running in the simulator.  With a WGVA800 skin, everything I try on the sim--including sample apps--reports a width of 480, except for my app which reports a width of 320 even though it's full screen.

Comment: "If the application states that it does not support different screen densities, the platform auto-scales any absolute pixel coordinates, pixel dimension values, and pixel math used in the application (such as might be used for specifying the width or padding for a view). It does this to ensure that pixel-defined screen elements are displayed at approximately the same physical size as they would be at the baseline density of "medium" (160). The platform handles this scaling transparently to the application and also reports scaled overall pixel dimensions to the application"

Comment: Previous text is a fragment from: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens%5Fsupport.html

Comment: Putting it as an answer in case it answers your question. Cos I wanna sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens%5Fsupport.html , if you don't declare support for multiple densities in your Manifest, then it will report medium resolution and the application will behave as such. Says:

> If the application states that it does
>   not support different screen
>   densities, the platform auto-scales
>   any absolute pixel coordinates, pixel
>   dimension values, and pixel math used
>   in the application (such as might be
>   used for specifying the width or
>   padding for a view). It does this to
>   ensure that pixel-defined screen
>   elements are displayed at
>   approximately the same physical size
>   as they would be at the baseline
>   density of "medium" (160). The
>   platform handles this scaling
>   transparently to the application and
>   also reports scaled overall pixel
>   dimensions to the application, rather
>   than physical pixel dimensions.
>
> For instance, suppose a given device
>   is
>   using a WVGA high-denisty screen,
>   which is 480x800 and about the same
>   size as a traditional HVGA screen, but
>   it's running an app that states that
>   it does not support multiple
>   densities. In this case, the system
>   will "lie" to the application when it
>   queries for screen dimensions, and
>   report 320x533. Then, when the app
>   does drawing operations, such as
>   invalidating the rectangle from
>   (10,10) to (100, 100), the system will
>   likewise automatically transform the
>   coordinates by scaling them the
>   appropriate amount, and actually
>   invalidate the region (15,15) to (150,
>   150). The same thing happens in the
>   other direction, if the application is
>   running on a lower-density screen,
>   coordinates are scaled down.

Answer (score 3):

The values are indeed specified in pixels. It sounds like your app is running in compatibility mode?

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  The instruction verbiage (copied in Vicente's answer) threw me a bit. "If the application states that it does not support different screen densities..." I took to mean that I explicitly added something to the manifest saying I don't support different resolution.  Rather, I needed to add something saying that I DO support any screen resolution. Not a big deal, but I thought I'd mention in since I know your on the Google team.  (Great Google IO vids BTW for a newbie like me...)

Answer (score 0):

This is something I have also been working on recently.  Is it the anyDensity tag that you are talking about within ?

If so, where is it suppsed to appear in the Manifest?

Regards,

Oliver

Comment: Yes. I used Eclipse to add it, but this appeared directly under the <manifest> tag:  

<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go - Oliver